# PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc creating server error 500

Tags: php

I am in the process of transferring some code to another server, and with a particular database function have come across a server error 500 (internal server error). I have narrowed it down to this line:

```
$foo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['FOO'];
```

The strange thing is that this works perfectly on the existing server but not the new one, yet breaking it down into two lines works:

```
$bar1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$bar2 = $bar1['BAR'];
```

I'm stumped by this, is there something obviously wrong?

Comment: Different PHP/mysqli versions ?

Comment: @frz3993 Turns out that is correct, as is the duplicate link that has been added. Old server was 5.4, new one is 5.3